# How to get or know first item in ListView only showing

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I want to get only the ListViewItem that is displayed on the screen in the ListView.
Visible ListViewItem changed frequently with scroll.
so, I try to get item using ContainerContentChanging, but i get with unnecessary items(ContainerContentChanging also gets the items that are not displayed, rendered item).

I attach my app capture, i want to get item Red marking dynamically.

How to i get?

[image]

Comment: Please share your current code

Comment: @AdamMcMahon https://github.com/sviom/UWP_ListScroll/blob/master/ListScrollResearch/ListResearch.xaml.cs
Here, Thanks

Comment: Why did you want to get the first item in the visible area of the ListView? Could you describe your detailed requirement?